# SQL- CONSTRAINT

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

Is it possible to create a table that automatically update a column value depending on another column value?

For example, I need to create a table of GRADES:

`GRADES-> STUDENT_ID
         GRADE1
         GRADE2
         GRADE3
         FINAL_GRADE`

I want the the value in the final grade will be equal to the last grade that is not null.
for example,

```
(studentid = 12345 grade1 = null grade2 = null grade3 = null finalgrade =null)
(studentid = 12345 grade1 = 80 grade2 = null grade3 = null finalgrade =80)
(studentid = 12345 grade1 = 80 grade2 = 75 grade3 = null finalgrade =75)
(studentid = 12345 grade1 = 80 grade2 = 75 grade3 = 90 finalgrade =90)
```

Comment: I assume the second `grade2` in each line should really be `grade3`?

Comment: Looks to me like your data model is flawed.  Can a student only ever have a max of 3 'grades'.  (What, in the real world, does 'grade' represent here?)  In the absence of additional information, I'd be inclined to have each 'grade' as a row in  child table of the STUDENT table.  Google 'data normalization' and 'third normal form'.

Comment: @EdStevens you are right, but I didnt wrote the all table i just looked for the function i needed. the original table as PK student_id and PK course_id so every student can up to grades in a course and the last 1 is the final grade of the course

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is something called a [virtual column](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/cncpt/tables-and-table-clusters.html#GUID-E32FDAD3-0D1E-4F16-B1A2-7F821D63177F):

```
alter table grades
add final_grade generated always as (coalesce(grade3,grade2,grade1));
```

The `coalesce` function returns the first of its arguments that is not null.

Note that you cannot insert or update values in a virtual column, they are computed by the database.

Comment: I tried the coalesce function but the function expecting values and not column names;
Im using oracle mabye this is the problem?

Comment: this is the error i get:

Error starting at line : 1 in command -
alter table table1
add final_grade number generated always as(coalesce(grade3,grade2.grad1))
Error report -
ORA-00904: "GRADE2"."GRAD1": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: You have put `.` (dot) after `GRADE2`. replace it with the `,` (comma).

Comment: same error:

Error starting at line : 1 in command -
alter table table1
add final_grade  generated always as(coalesce(grade3,grade2,grad1))
Error report -
ORA-00904: "GRADE2": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:

if I put value like 1 2 3 its working but not with column names

Comment: @Tejash problem solved im so sorry i had spelling error !
thank you so much !!